# React MUI Clockwise padding properties

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Does Mui Box have any padding shorthand properties? for clockwise syntax?

This does not work and gives syntax error.

```
<Box padding = {2 1 1 2}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, no -- `padding`/`p` only accepts a single spacing value. If you do not want to use the [longhand properties](https://mui.com/system/properties/#properties-reference-table) provided (`pt`, `pr`, `pb`, `pl`), and need to pass them as a list for some reason, your best bet is to provide a function to the `padding`/`p` prop from which the [Box](https://mui.com/system/react-box/) can derive the values *(if you don't want to use `sx`)*.  For example:

```
<Box
  padding={(theme) => theme.spacing(2, 1, 1, 2)}
/>
```

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/box-padding-example-r6v28m?file=/demo.tsx